# php mail body issue

Tags: php, html

I have been working on a Company Extension List. The only thing that isn't working is when the admin adds a new user on a form in the extension list, I want it to email the form details to my boss so every time someone gets added he knows about it.

I read up a bit since I'm very new to php but I found this `mailto` html command and it works well putting the subject line in and the right email address but the body looks horrible. its all mixed up like this:

```
name:jurgen&extension number:242&email:aksda@skdna.com&mode=added
```

I have read up about php scripting for emails but i am confused on how to do it. Could someone show me a way to accomplish this? I want the first button to send the email and then the second button must be shown to add the data into the database.

my current code:

```
<form name="form1" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?mode=added" method="post">
<div align="center"><table class="searchable">
<tr><td>Extension:</td><td><div align="center">
<input type="text" name="ext" required />
<span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
</div></td></tr>
<tr><td>Name:</td><td><div align="center">
<input type="text" name="name" required />
<span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
</div></td></tr>
 <tr><td>Department:</td><td><div align="center"><select name="department" required>
            <option value="VW NEW CARS ADMIN AND STOCK CONTROL">Value 4</option>
            <option value="value 5">value 5</option>
            <option value="value 6">value 6</option>
            <option value="value 3">value 3</option>
            <option value="value 4">value 4</option>
    </select>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
</div></td></tr>
<tr><td>Email:</td><td><div align="center">
<input type="text" name="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" name="email" title="Example: user@company.co.za" required/>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
</div></td></tr>
<tr><td>Cellphone:</td><td><div align="center">
<input type="text" name="phone" />
</div></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center">| <button type="submit" formaction="mailto:email@address.com?subject=New User Added To Extension List" enctype="text/plain" method="get">Email Boss</button>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><a href="javascript:history.go(-1);">Back</a> | <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"  value="Add New Contact"<?php if($disable ==1){?>disabled<?php } ?>/></td></tr>
<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="added">
```

Comment: Please add your try and edit your question.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @limonik edited sir

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to establish a good body design in your email use html,
for example :

```
                                    $to = $email;
                                $message = "
                                <table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3'>
                                   <tr>
                                    <td colspan=2><b>SignalShare</b></td>
                                  </tr>
                                   <tr>
                                    <td colspan=2>Thank you for creating an account.</td>
                                  </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <hr><h3>Account info</h3><hr>
                                    <table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3'>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td width='28%' >Username : </td>
                                    <td width='72%'>".$username."</td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>Email : </td>
                                    <td>".$email."</td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>
                                <p>SignalChat advise you not to delete this email for it contains informations that could be in use later.</p>
                                    <hr><h3>Account activation</h3><hr>
                                    <p>If you wish to activate your account please use the following link : </p>
                                    <p><a href = 'localhost/SignalShare/activate.php?code=$code&user=$username' style = 'text-decoration: none; color: blue;' >Activate account</a></p>
                                    <hr>
                                    <p>If this email does not concern you please ignore it.</p>
                                    <p>All regards.</p>
                                    <p>SignalShare.</p>
                                    ";
                                $subject = "Accout activation";                                 
                                $headers  = "From: SignaShare\r\n";
                                $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; 

                                mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);        
                                header("Location: success.php?email=".$email."");
```

As you can see I am using tables and html tags to help tidy up the email, and if you notice in the $headers I added $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
If this is not what you asked for please comment here so I can edit my answer and good luck